# How can I add username and password to Apache tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

This is first time,I installed Apache tomcat 6.0.While initialization time I forget-ted to mention any userName and Password.after completion of initialization I faced one problem while  I tried to open `tomcat-Manager` it asking `user-name and password` but specifically I didn't mention any `userName and password`.so how can I set up `UserName and password`.

I hope,you understood what my problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill your server, add the username/password combo to tomcat-users.xml and restart the JVM:

```
<user username="subbu" password="stupidpasswordhere" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui,manager"/>
```

Comment: How can I add username and password.even I don't know the syntaxes.can you tell me clearly.

Comment: I added the following code in between `<tomcat-users>`,but it's not working.

`<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>`

Comment: Your roles are wrong... for manager website access you need the manager-gui role.

Comment: `hd1` I reopen Apache-Tomcat,and selected `Tomcat-Manager`.this time it's not asking username and password but I don't want like this.If I reopen again it should ask username and password.

How can i set this?

Comment: Try closing your browser and reopening it?

Comment: working fine.but tell me one thing,what is relation with browser.